# Run PHP scripts stored inside Rails directory structure

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails

I built a PHP application using Drupal and I want it to run under the same domain where Rails is running. So for example  I have **mysite.com** running on Ruby on Rails, I would like to install and run Drupal in **mysite.com/my_drupal_application**.

I tried creating a subfolder inside rails , on the same level as apps and models directories but that did not worked. I tried moving creating a subfolder in the **public** directory too but it didnt worked either.

Maybe rails is confusing the url to be calling a controller? So what else should i do then?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: do not mix the directories at all, use your vhost config to declare whats what, look at the alias directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Drupal and rails have their own routing logic. Drupal stores it in both the database and the `hook_menu`, rails has it defined in the router.rb. They *will* conflict at some point.

So, the advice is to run your Drupal app on either a different subdomain, defined in a virtual-host. Alternatively you can define vhosts that define urls where your rails and Drupal app run.  You should run them next to one another, and never inside one another.

Comment: Right. I ended up putting Drupal in it's own directory under a sub domain.